# SQL select where one parameter equals to another one in another table

Tags: sql, join

I'm very new to the SQL table joins and I need some help.

I have two tables, no. one looks like this (let's call this TableA):

```
    Fogado_felh_id   Kuldo_felh_id
    -------------------------------
    35               33
    35               38
    35               NULL
    35               39
```

And the other one looks like this (and call this TableB):

```
    id               Login_name
    ---------------------------------------
    33               somebody@emailhere.com
    38               SomeUserName
```

I would like to join these tables so I get the login names based on the 'Kuldo_felh_id' and also keep the entire TableA content.

So I wrote this SQL query command:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, b.login_nev 
FROM
    TableA a, TableB b 
WHERE
    fogado_felh_id = 35 
    AND b.id = a.kuldo_felh_id;
```

It returns this:

```
    Fogado_felh_id   Kuldo_felh_id   Login_name
    -----------------------------------------------------------
    35               33              somebody@emailhere.com
    35               38              SomeUserName
```

The problem is that this command doesn't return the lines where the kuldo_felh_id is null or the id doesn't exist in TableB. How can I return tableA content where it doesn't exist in TableB?

This is the output I would like to see:

```
    Fogado_felh_id   Kuldo_felh_id   Login_name
    --------------------------------------------------------
    35               33              somebody@emailhere.com
    35               38              SomeUserName
    35               NULL            NULL //Because it does not exist the login_name should be null
    35               39              NULL //Because it does not exist the login_name should be null
```

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN`. Do not use the old style joins `TableA a, TableB`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get what you are looking for. Notice the `LEFT JOIN` syntax. Include the `ON` keyword to specify what is joining the 2 tables. Once you start aliasing, alias all of the query columns.

```
SELECT a.*, b.login_nev 
from TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON b.id = a.kuldo_felh_id
where a.fogado_felh_id = 35
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver!